# Как вывести случайную строку из файла?

Tags: python, файлы, циклы

У меня есть файл, в котором несколько строк. Как выводить из него строки случайным образом? Нужно ли использовать для этого модуль random?

```
word = "Имя"

fileQuestion = open(f"question/{word}.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") #output
fileQuestion.readlines()
           
for i in fileQuestion:
...
```

Вывод, который нужно получить:

```
Содержимое первой строки
```

или

```
Содержимое второе строки
```

Comment: `print(random.choice(fileQuestion.readlines()))`

Comment: @andreymal Это работает, отпишите в ответе, поставлю галочку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(random.choice(fileQuestion.readlines()))` - помогает в этом случае. Оно действительно выводит рандомную строку. Спасибо @andreymal за помощь